# Group by with UNION

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

My code is not grouping properly, it still doesn't group [Reden uitstroom2] and [Reden uitstroom3] with [Reden uitstroom1]. The count works properly but its showing duplicates in [Reden Uitstroom1].

For Example:

Reden uitstroom1 = 1x A / 2x B
Reden uitstroom2 = 1x A / 1x B

Aantal Uitstroom 2014 - Reden Uitstroom1
1                     - A
1                     - A
2                     - B
1                     - B

Which Should be:

Aantal Uitstroom 2014 - Reden Uitstroom1
2 - A
3 - B

I can't seem to change [Reden Uitstroom1] into [Reden Uitstroom] because then it returns numbers instead of A / B...

```sql
SELECT        Count(Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom1]) AS [Aantal Uitstroom 2014],
                   (Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom1]) AS [Reden Uitstroom1]

FROM          Klantinformatie     

INNER JOIN    Hertoetsing 
    ON        Klantinformatie.KlantID=Hertoetsing.Klantid

WHERE         (((Year(Hertoetsing.[Datum uitstroom1]))=2014))

GROUP BY      Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom1]

UNION ALL

SELECT        Count(Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom2]) AS [Aantal Uitstroom 2014],
                   (Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom2]) AS [Reden Uitstroom1]

FROM          Klantinformatie 

INNER JOIN    Hertoetsing 
    ON        Klantinformatie.KlantID=Hertoetsing.Klantid

WHERE         (((Year(Hertoetsing.[Datum uitstroom2]))=2014))

GROUP BY      Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom2]

UNION ALL

SELECT        Count(Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom3]) AS [Aantal Uitstroom 2014],
                   (Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom3]) AS [Reden Uitstroom1]

FROM          Klantinformatie 

INNER JOIN    Hertoetsing 
    ON        Klantinformatie.KlantID=Hertoetsing.Klantid

WHERE         (((Year(Hertoetsing.[Datum uitstroom3]))=2014))

GROUP BY      Hertoetsing.[Reden uitstroom3];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the query in another `SELECT`, i.e.

```
SELECT 
    Sum ([Aantal Uitstroom 2014]) AS [Aantal Uitstroom 2014], 
    [Reden Uitstroom]
FROM
(
     [UNION query goes here]

)
GROUP BY [Reden Uitstroom]
```

Without the `SELECT` wrapper, all it's doing is appending the results of each individual `Count` as there is no summation or grouping applied to it.

Comment: Thanks it's working! Just one problem... [Reden Uitstroom] returns numbers, when there are no numbers to be found lol... 1-2-3-4-5-6-7-9

Comment: It's taking the numbers from another table, for example 1 is a certain reason in a drop down list and 2 is the next reason etc.